# Как получить код нажатой клавиши в хуке Delphi.

Tags: windows, hook, delphi

Здравствуйте.
Есть функция обработки хука на клавиатуру:

```
function KeyBoardProc(ACode: Integer; AWParam :WParam; AMsg: PMsg): LRESULT; stdcall;
begin
if AWPARAM = WM_KEYUP then
form1.Caption:=Inttostr(AMSG.message);
result:=CallNextHookEx(hh,ACode,AWParam,LongInt(Amsg));
end;
```

Эта функция обрабатывает хук неправильно, т.к структура PMsg возвращает не порядковый номер ASCII символа, а его порядковый номер на клавиатуре...как быть? Прошу помощи. Спасибо...

---

**С меня 25 очков =)**

Comment: >> Все! Жаль, что никто не ответил, но я нашел свой способ! Способ достаточно замысловат =)

все же осмелюсь предположить что плясать нужно от текущей раскладки клавиатуры, GetKeyboardLayout.

Также могу предположить что перехватывать нужно WM_CHAR в хуке WH_GETMESSAGE

Comment: @shurik, а не могли бы привести пример, пожалуйста. Очень прошу.

Comment: а, @shurik ?

Answer (score 1):

Да тоже самое, только вместо `WH_KEYBOARD` ставите `WH_GETMESSAGE`

```
function GetMsgProc()(Code: Integer; wParam, lParam: Longint): Longint;
```

MSDN - [GetMsgProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644981(v=vs.85).aspx)

Вот ссылочку с примером [нашел](http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=180516&hl=). Там и исходники есть. Думаю разберетесь.